# what is Limit load factor structural and aerodynamic envelope at structural design gross weight and maximum gross weight?

Tags: aerodynamics, helicopter, aircraft-structures, vtol

As an aerospace engineer, as soon as I saw the words "structural and aerodynamic envelope" the first thing that popped into my mind that is it V-n diagram? But when I searched about it in the internet I found so many different answers. Now I am confused. I need this answer for a competition documentation part. They want this envelope for a VTOL aircraft.

Comment: What have you found for example? And what's the exact question from the competition documentation? Do you have a link to it?

Comment: i found velocity vs altitude graphs of some helicopters, but i need this for a VTOL aircraft
link- https://vtol.org/files/dmfile/rfp_sikorskyhvstol_40thsdc_2022-23_final.pdf
2.4.9 (1)

Comment: What a very interesting RFP they have this year! Anyway I also don't get what they're asking about here: there's a way to ask question to the VFS?